# A different method is also getting triggered when calling a method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

When calling a method, a different method which hasn't been called is also getting called.

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo 'http://localhost/LinkLab/index.php/Comments/insertcomment/'.$postarray[0]->postID; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="1" required placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            <br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" required placeholder="Comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submitbtn" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function insertcomment($postID){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('comments_model');
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');

        if ($this->input->post('submit') == true){
            $commentarray = array(
                'postID' => $postID,
                'commentID' => round(microtime(true)*1000),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
                'timestamp' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
            );
            $result = $this->comments_model->inserCommentToDB($commentarray);
        }
        header('Location:http://localhost/LinkLab/index.php/Comments/'.$postID);
}
```

**Model**

```
class Comments_model extends CI_Model {

    function retrievePostFromDB($postID) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE postID = ".$postID;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $postarray = $query->result();
        return $postarray;
    }
    function inserCommentToDB($commentarray) {
        print_r($commentarray);
        $this->db->insert('comments', $commentarray);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller, when it calls the "inserCommentToDB" method, it seems like the "retrievePostFromDB" method is also getting called as it seems. It gives out the following error.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'insertcomment' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM post WHERE postID = insertcomment
>
> Filename: C:/wamp/www/LinkLab/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

What is causing this and what would be the fix? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the world of SQL-injection. You're concatenating the value into the select-query, and it needs to be escaped into a string; this is hard however and often leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities. You might want to look into libraries that provide prepared statements or similar.

Comment: Just a tip where you action is in form use the  `<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>` make sure base_url is set of course in config.php

Answer (score 0):

To get help regarding your problem you'll need to provide more information like index function in your Comments controller & if you are using _remap method or not + the contents of your route.php file

As for the provided code; I have a few comments to improve it.

1- If your system is using a specific time-zone; set the time-zone in your index.php file (you do not need to set the time-zone each time you want to insert or update things).

2- Use form_helper to build your form or at least just use the form_open method if you prefer to write your forms manually, or you could just use site_url to link your form instead of manually wiring your form to localhost; currently your script requires modifications in-order to upload to a webhost.

3- Use form_validation library to validate you're not posting an empty comment; checking if user is submitting a form isn't doing you any good.

4- CodeIgniter has a redirect function which you can use instead of manually using header function; This would allow you to redirect using 'controller/method' so you don't have to lock yourself to localhost (Again save you time when you need to upload to a webhost)

5- Since you're using comments model, you don't have to use the word 'comment' in your methods; it's redundant.

6- Comments model has nothing to do with retrieving a post, You should retrieve your posts from a posts_model.

7- Use query builder to avoid SQL injections, it will automatically escape the values you use in your 'where' statement.

8- Although the way you're generating comment ids appears to be fine; Normally you should be using an auto_increment id to avoid having to calculate an id yourself.

9- If you use a helper or library in too many locations then use autoload.php to load these so they become available across all methods in your application; As for model loading normally you load these in your __construct for example every single method in a posts controller will be using posts_model therefore having it loaded in __construct will save your time & effort

Finally I think using camel-case to name your SQL columns is a bad habit; I prefer using all lower-case with underscores to separate words, but this is just a matter of preference.